Applying Symbology to Feature Layer from ArcGIS toolbox
I'm running into an issue applying a symbology layer (.lyrx) to a feature layer from an ArcGIS Toolbox.  I am able to apply the symbology manually as well as through the ArcGIS terminal window without any issues.  I have seen a number of posts with others having similar issues but not great resolution.
Any suggestions on how to add the "raster_to_point_out_path" file to the ArcGIS project, then apply the symbology through an ArcGIS toolbox?
  # Add the point feature class to the map
  aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
  active_map = aprx.activeMap
  # Apply symbology from .lyrx file
  symbology_lyrx = r"Modeling.lyrx"

 # Add the point feature class to the map
 added_layer = active_map.addDataFromPath(raster_to_point_out_path)
 arcpy.AddMessage(f"Layer added to map for Dir_Arrow{value}")

 # Apply symbology from .lyrx file
 symbology_layer = arcpy.mp.LayerFile(symbology_lyrx)
 arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(added_layer, symbology_layer)
 arcpy.AddMessage("Symbology applied from the .lyrx file")
    


Is the layer added but the symbology not applied or is the layer not added? I notice that the symbology_lyrx doesn't have a fully qualified path, is this because of obfuscation or is the path as stated?

I can confirm. This tool is not working from script. So, add lyrx and replace it's datasource or connection

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/465755/arcpy-script-to-apply-symbology-to-layers-works-in-the-python-window-but-not-as#465786

The "raster_to_point_out_path" is an output from earlier in the script.  The script I have above will add the layer to the map, though I'm having issues when I try to apply the symbology to that layer which was just added.  For the lyrx file, I just removed the beginning portion of the location for privacy reasons.

This seems to have resolved the issue.  Thanks @FelixIP, your suggestion helped me resolve this!
try:
            symbology_lyrx = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(8)
            # Update this with the prefix for the output
            DA = "Directional_Arrow"  

            # Add data from the given path and assign it to variable L
            L = active_map.addDataFromPath(raster_to_point_out_path)

            # Get the first layer from the list of layers that match the criteria 'Directional_Arrow'
            layers = [layer for layer in active_map.listLayers() if DA in layer.name]
            if not layers:
                raise Exception(f"No layers found matching the criteria '{DA}'")
            lyr = layers[0]

            # Get the symbology (styling and visual representation) of the newly added layer
            symbology_layer = arcpy.mp.LayerFile(symbology_lyrx)

            # Apply the symbology from the symbology_layer to the lyr
            lyr.symbology = symbology_layer.listLayers()[0].symbology

        except Exception as e:
            arcpy.AddMessage(f"Symbology Failed: {e}")

